# What is the definition for "location" in a kindle eBook?

Tags: kindle

I was navigating about this text I'm currently reading and I grew curious what exactly is meant by `Loc` or `Location` in the context of a kindle book. Is this essentially a word or character count?

If you look at the screen shot below I outlined in red the section of the UI that points out the text progress. There it states `Page 14 × Loc 358` at the slider bar, and in the status bar `5% - Page 14 of 393 - Location 358 of 7091`
[image: Kindle Location Progress Bar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [MobileRead Wiki](https://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Page_numbers#Implementation), a location is 150 bytes.

> The Kindle uses an absolute position system named locations which are
>   actually every 150 bytes in the file. Easy to generate accurately but
>   are much smaller than a standard page so you get a range of numbers on
>   every page. The exact formula is floor(bytes/150)+1, and note that
>   this is bytes, not characters, and includes all the markup and tags in
>   the mobi-html, not just the displayed text.